How to understand Peter Lax's proof of the radius of convergence for power series?
I am confused by Peter Lax's proof of the convergence radius of power series.

In the initial part of the proof, I believe that the conclusion is based on the assumption that $|x-a|<|x_0-a|$, but Lax states that it holds for all $x$.


Let us first point out that if the series converges at some ...


The e-book I am using is the second edition of Spring, but it seems to be a printing error here.


set $r = \frac{|x_0-a|}{|x−a|}$


In the proof, the so-called three possible cases, I believe that the first and third cases are the same.

I am completely confused about the entire proof. I think the third case explanation is enough to complete the proof of the theorem. But I don't understand the first case. Why prove the first case?
Here is the original article, It's a bit long
Theorem 2.13. For a power series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_{n}(x-a)^n$, one of the following must hold:
$(a)$ The series converges absolutely for every $x$.
$(b)$ The series converges only at $x = a$.
$(c)$ There is a positive number $R$, called the radius of convergence, such that the series converges absolutely for $|x−a| < R$ and diverges for $|x−a| > R$. In case $(c)$, the series might or might not converge at $x = a−R$ and at $x = a+R$.
Proof. Let us first point out that if the series converges at some $x_0 = a$, then it converges absolutely for every $x$ that is closer to $a$, that is, $|x − a| < |x_0 − a|$. Here is why: The convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_{n}(x-a)^n$ implies that the terms $c_{n}(x-a)^n$ tend to $0$.
In particular, there is an $N$ such that $|c_n(x_0 − a)^n| < 1$ for all $n > N$. If $0 < |x−a| < |x_0 −a|$, set $r = \frac{|x_0-a|}{|x−a|}$ . Then $r < 1$, and we get :
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=N+1}|c_{n}(x-a)^n| = \sum^{\infty}_{n=N+1}|c_{n}(x-a)^n | \Bigl|\frac{(x_0-a)^n}{(x_0-a)^n}\Bigl|
$$
$$
=\sum^{\infty}_{n=N+1}|c_{n}(x_0-a)^n | \Bigl|\frac{(x-a)^n}{(x_0-a)^n}\Bigl| \leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=N+1}r^n.
$$
Therefore, $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_{n}(x-a)^n$ converges absolutely by comparison with a geometric series.
Now consider the three possibilities we have listed in the theorem. It might happen that the series converges for every $x$. If so, it converges absolutely for every $x$ by what we have just shown. This covers the first case.
The other possibility is that the series converges for some number $x_0$, but not for every number. If there is only one such $x_0$, then it must be $a$, since the series
$$
c_0 +c_1(a−a) +c_2(a−a)^2 +\dots = c_0
$$
certainly converges. This covers the second case.
Finally, there may be an $x_0 \neq a$ for which the series converges, though the series does not converge for every number. We will use the least upper bound principle,Theorems 1.2 and 1.3, to describe $R$. Let $S$ be the set of numbers $x$ for which the series converges. Then $S$ is not empty, because $a$ and $x_0$ are in $S$, as well as every number closer to $a$ than $x_0$. Also, $S$ is bounded, because if there were arbitrarily large (positive or negative) numbers in $S$, then all numbers closer to $a$ would be in $S$, i.e., $S$ would be all the numbers. Therefore, $S$ has a least upper bound $M$ and a greatest lower bound $m$, which means that if
$$m < x < M,$$ then the series converges at $x$. We ask you in Problem 2.65 to show that $m$ and $M$ are the same distance from $a$:
$$
m < a < M  \quad and \quad  a−m = M −a
$$
and that the convergence is absolute in $(m,M)$. Set $R = M − a$. This concludes the proof.

Don't pay attention to what an author said verbatim, pay attention to what makes sense
